# Wordpress 6.3: WP All Import not taking images from Network Media Library

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, multisite

Setup: WordPress 6.3 Multisite with Woocommerce

Plugins: [Network Media Library](https://github.com/humanmade/network-media-library) and [WP All Import](https://www.wpallimport.com/)

Network Media Library is set up to take images from **Site 1**. WP All Import is activated on all multisite sub-sites.

While all other images when accessed from the Media library point to xyz.com/sub-site-2/wp-content/uploads/2023 because of the Network Media Library.

When a category/product import is run using WP All Import it looks for the images within xyz.com/sub-site-2/wp-content/uploads/sites

As a result, the images don't get attached/linked as category images.

I tried using the following code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function custom_image_import_callback($post_id, $att_id, $filepath, $is_keep_existing_images) {
    // Store the current blog ID
    $current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

    // Switch to the central media library site
    switch_to_blog(1); // Use the correct site ID here

    // Get the file path using the attachment ID from the central media library site
    $file_path = get_attached_file($att_id);

    if ($file_path) {
        // Prepare the arguments for wp_insert_attachment
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg', // Change as needed based on your image type
            'post_title' => basename($file_path), // Use the filename as the title
            'post_content' => '', // No content needed
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );

        // Insert the attachment
        $imported_image_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_path, $post_id);

        if (!is_wp_error($imported_image_id)) {
            // Set image as the featured image for the imported post
            set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $imported_image_id);
        }
    }

    // Switch back to the original site
    restore_current_blog();
}
add_action('pmxi_gallery_image', 'custom_image_import_callback', 10, 4);
```

When I deactivate Network Media Library and upload images to the sub-site media library and then upload categories via WP All Import the category images show, the moment I activate Network Media library the images no longer show.

I'm not sure how to go about sorting/fixing this?

Comment: As this seems to be a bug related to some 3rd Party plugins, you should report that issue in their respective support threads, it will be more efficient for everybody. Also, for many reasons, you should not use WooCommerce in a multisite configuration, if you plan to have a serious strong working e-commerce platform.